# How to use "colcon build" in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ros2

I am trying to create a docker image based on ubuntu:20.04 where I want to install ROS2, ignition gazebo and the ROS2-ign-bridge with a Dockerfile.

The installation of ROS2 and ign work without any issue but during the bridge installation I need to use colcon. Heres that part from the Dockerfile:

```
## install ROS2 ignition gazebo bridge
RUN export IGNITION_VERSION=edifice
RUN mkdir -p ros_ign_bridge_ws/src
RUN git clone https://github.com/osrf/ros_ign.git -b foxy ros_ign_bridge_ws/src
WORKDIR ros_ign_bridge_ws
RUN rosdep install -r --from-paths src -i -y --rosdistro foxy
RUN colcon build
RUN source ros_ign_bridge_ws/install/setup.bash
RUN echo "source ros_ign_bridge_ws/install/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

It fails during the `colcon build` step when I use

`docker build -f Dockerfiles/companion_base.Dockerfile -t companion_base .`

, but when I run the image created up to that step

`docker run -it  c125a17c2f68 /bin/bash`

and then execute `colcon build` inside the container it works without any issue.

So what is the difference between `RUN colcon build` and running `colcon build` inside the container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that when you source something in a previous docker build step, it isn't available in the next step. So what I needed to do was do the sourcing and building in the same step:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash; colcon build"
```